# Python 3x : Importing Math library python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which i want to execute :

```
import math

class A(object): 

    def someNum(self, num): 
        num = int(math.log2(num))
        return num

a = A()
a.someNum('9')
```

> But it throws an exception :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    a.numToLoc('9')
  File "main.py", line 30, in numToLoc
    num = int(math.log2(num))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log2'
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Comment: `math.log2()` was added in Python 3.3; you're apparently using an older version.  Try `math.log(num, 2)` instead.

Comment: @MEdwin i am using 3x

Comment: which 3x. they're not all the same. theres 3.0 through to 3.7

Comment: @Gammer Your also passing a string to `somenum()`. I think you want to pass an integer instead: `a.someNum(9)`

Comment: which exact version of Python are you using? 3.3, 3.6...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`math.log2` was introduced in [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/math.html#math.log2). You are probably using an earlier version.

In those earlier versions, you can use

```
math.log(num, 2)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file called `math.py` in the same directory as the code you're trying to run. Delete or rename it.

When you `import math`, Python walks through the directories in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) and imports the first file called `math.py` (or a directory called `math` with an `__init__.py` file inside) that it sees. The first entry in `sys.path` is the current directory, so it sees your `math.py` first.

See the documentation for [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) or for [the `import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Answer (score -1):

As already suggested either use Python3.3 or above
or
use `math.log(num, 2)`

Another slight modification is required.

Please change

`a.someNum('9')`

to

```
a.someNum(9)
```

Else this error occurs.

```
TypeError: a float is required
```